# Helm, evaluate linux env variable in values.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following variable JVM_ARGS

*base-values.yaml*

```
app:
  env:
    PORT: 8080
    ...
    JVM_ARGS: >
      -Dspring.profiles.active=$(SPRING_PROFILE),test
      -Dspring.config.additional-location=/shared
      -javaagent:/app/dd-java-agent.jar
```

*service-x-values.yaml*

```
app:
  env:
    SPRING_PROFILE: my-local-profile
```

Values file are evaluated is the order:

- base-values.yaml
- service-x-values.yaml

I need JVM_ARGS to be evaluated against SPRING_PROFILE and so far I cannot make it work.
What is the best way to do something like that?

I'm new to helm and Kubernetes and have a feeling that I'm missing something basic.

What I tried:
defining JVM_ARGS surrounded with double quotes and without them.

**UPD:**
The problem was that I had some custom Helm charts built by the other devs and I had little knowledge how those charts worked. I only worked with values files which were applied against the chart templates.

I wanted the property to be resolved by helm to

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=my-local-profile,vault
```

At the end I decided to see how Spring Boot itself resolves properties and came up with the following:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILE},vault
```

Since spring.profiles.active is a regular property, env variables are allowed there and Spring will resolve the property at the runtime which worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm a bit confused: are you referring to an environment variable (as in the title of the question) or to a helm value?
2. Helm does not evaluate environment variables in the value files. `$(SPRING_PROFILE)` is treated as a literal string, it's not eveluated.
3. Actually Helm does not evaluate ANYTHING in the value files. They are source of data, not templates. Placeholders (actually [GO templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)) are evaluated only inside template files.
4. As a consequence of the point 3., you cannot reference one helm variable from another.

If you really need to get Spring Profiles from a Linux environment variable, you could achieve it by setting Helm variable when calling helm install and the like (although using --set is considered a bad practice):

```sh
helm install --set app.env.spring_profile=$SPRING_PROFILE ...
```

Although even than, `app.env.spring_profile` couldn't be evaluated inside `base-values.yaml`. You would need to move it directly to your template file, e.g.:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          ...
          env:
            SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: {{- .Values.app.env.spring_profile }},test
```

Comment: Thanks, at the end I came up with the solution not involving Helm, although I do know I need to learn it better :) because I didn't understand some basic concepts  which made me spend a few hours on that problem.

Comment: Do you have a source for why is --set considered bad practice?